# Unity3D integration with Eclipse for Android project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to integrate Unity3D project with eclipse following this example: http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Manual/Android-Integrating%20Unity%20With%20Eclipse.html

The guide says, that you need to copy assets/libs and assets/bins of the library project to the same folders in the java project. However, when I'm trying go run it, it says following:

> 02-13 19:15:38.121: E/AndroidRuntime(5000):
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load mono: findLibrary
>   returned null

I would presume that copying assets/libs to /libs would help, but then eclipse cleans root libs folder every time I build the project.

Why Unity can not load the library from assets/libs if they guide says that it should be there?

Comment: What's your assets code type (I mean your script code type) , JavaScript or ...?

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem. It worked when I exported the apk file to the smartphone. It is still giving the same problem in the LogCat but it works in my smartphone. Good luck.